# Как настроить редактор Breackets, чтобы при указании класса одного из элементов появлялся выбор?

Tags: css

Как в редакторе Breackets настроить, чтобы при указании класса одного из элементов появлялся выбор, как на скриншоте ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В скриншоте редактор PHP Шторм, а я пользуюсь Breackets. Подскажите какой плагин установить ?

P.S.: у меня есть *emmet*, но он классы не делает выпадающие варианты

Comment: м.б. Adobe Brackets , а не Breackets? опечатка ?